# Where to munge websocket data in Ember Data

Tags: websocket, ember-data, data-munging

I'm writing a web socket service for my Ember app. The service will subscribe to a URL, and receive data. The data will push models into Ember Data's `store`.

The URL scheme does not represent standard RESTful routes; it's not `/posts` and `/users`, for example, it's something like `/inbound`. Once I subscribe it will just be a firehose of various events.

For each of these routes I subscribe to, I will need to implementing data munging specific to that route, to get the data into a format Ember Data expects. My question is, where is the best place to do this?

An example event object I'll receive:

```
event: {
  0: "device:add",
  1: {
    device: {
      devPath: "/some/path",
      label: "abc",
      mountPath: "/some/path",
      serial: "abc",
      uuid: "5406-12F6",
      uniqueIdentifier: "f5e30ccd7a3d4678681b580e03d50cc5",
      mounted: false,
      files: [ ],
      ingest: {
        uniqueIdentifier: 123
        someProp: 123,
        anotherProp: 'abc'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to munge the data to be standardized, like this

```
device: {
  id: "f5e30ccd7a3d4678681b580e03d50cc5",
  devPath: "/some/path",
  label: "abc",
  mountPath: "/some/path",
  serial: "abc",
  uuid: "5406-12F6",
  mounted: false,
  files: [ ],
  ingestId: 123
},
ingest: {
  id: 123,
  someProp: 123,
  anotherProp: 'abc'
}
```

and then hand that off to *something* that will know how to add both the device model and the ingest model to the store. I'm just getting confused on all the abstractions in ember data.

Questions:

1. Which method should I pass that final, standardized JSON to in order to add the records to the store? `store.push`?
2. Where is the appropriate place for the initial data munging i.e. getting the event data from the array? Application serializer's `extractSingle`? `pushPayload`? Most of the munging will be non-standard across the different routes.
3. Should per-type serializers be used for each key in the data after I've done the initial munging? i.e. should I had initial "blob" to application serializer, which will then delegate each key to the per-model serializers?

References:

- [Docs on the store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#toc_store-createrecord-vs-push-vs-pushpayload-vs-update)
- [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_pushPayload)